# taking excel input and using it as data in jave

Tags: java, php, html, sql, excel

Okay so I want to right a piece of code that can help me accomplish the following task. I just want help on a pseudo code so I can start coding cause I have no idea how I am going to do this.

So what needs to be done is I need to create a line of flight using raw excel data. For example a flight takes off from MIA @ 9:59 arrives in ATL @ 12:00 now plane must sit at least 30 minutes on the ground before next flight. So now I have to look at the next flight that will be leaving from ATL which would be at say there are now flights leaving atl from 12:30 to 12:40 the next flight would be at 12:45 to SFO which will arrive at 18:08 in sfo. So this airplane made 2 legs, 1st leg to mia to atl and the 2nd leg would be atl to sfo. this is just the simple part but what if i want to determine

So I need to be able to go through all this data which looks like this [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0N4y.png). Be able to change make it look like this for each flight [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTJym.png)

Any feedback would help greatly

I am trying to implement this in either java, php/sql with html page or just with macros in excel

Answer (score 0):

Check out apache POI. As far as I know it was developed especially for reading Excel files. Plus it's also open source :).

Apache POI Link: [Click here](https://poi.apache.org/)

Example:

InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xls");
    //InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
if (cell == null)
    cell = row.createCell(3);
cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
cell.setCellValue("a test");

// Write the output to a file
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: Would I be able to also add code to go through the excel sheet to determine what i have mentioned above

Comment: @ShivPatel It works on windows, I have used it. And yes using there documentation you would be able to do what you originally asked in your question.

Comment: Okay I get that. But how would I desgin the code like what would the logic be. If i can get that information i should be able to code it